# Help in understanding 'reasonable' encoding of inputs

Tags: graphs, turing-machines, time-complexity, encoding-scheme

I read that a reasonable encoding of inputs is one where the length of the encoding is no more than a polynomial of the 'natural representation' of the input. For instance, binary encodings are reasonable, but unary encodings are not.

But say that the input is a graph, and its natural representation is a vertex and edge list. Suppose that the graph has $k$ vertices. If I use unary to encode, the overall length of the input referring to the vertex list would be $O(k^2)$, i.e. $=|1^1|+|1^2|+|1^3|+...+|1^k|$. Isn't this unary encoding still a polynomial with respect to the number of vertices of the graph (which is $k$)?

What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you think?  Why do you think it isn't?  Why do you think you are missing something?

Comment: @D.W., I think that 'at most a polynomial' of the length $N$ of the natural representation of the input should be something like within 'a logarithmic factor' of the length $N$ of the natural representation of the input, i.e. $\log_k(N)$, with $k \geq 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unary encoding for values 0 <= k <= N takes O(N) space. Unary encoding of an n-bit number takes $\Theta(2^n)$ space. See the difference?

Comment: does this mean that 'reasonable' encodings should at least be binary ? (i.e. n-bit numbers for n >= 2) ... in that case reasonable should be a logarithmic factor of  N and not at most polynomial to N, unlike what I read

Comment: No, it means that using unary representation for not very large numbers isn’t exactly clever, but it also isn’t totally unreasonable. For arbitrary large integers, it is an unreasonable encoding.